# Get default value for element from schema using xerces (C++)

Tags: c++, xsd, xerces, xerces-c

Say I have a schema which defines an element as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="Widget" type="tns:WidgetType" />

<xsd:complexType name="WidgetType">
  <xsd:sequence>

    <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:normalizedString" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
    <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:normalizedString" default="Unknown" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />

  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I'm parsing (DOM parser) an XML file that has been validated against this schema using Xerces-C++. If the `Description` element is present, I know how to read it by iterating through all the child elements of the `DOMElement` for a given `Widget` and using `DOMElement::getTextContent()` upon finding the `Description` element.

But, if a particular `Widget` element does not have a `Description` child element (which is allowed by the schema), how can I fetch the default value (`Unknown`) from the schema?

Thanks for your responses,
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use XPath or XQuery to query the schema document to grab any values off of the schema document. Xerces site says it has partial XPath support, and lists Xalan and XQilla if you need more power.

Comment: I'll have to take your word for this, never tried XPath or XQuery. But +1 for answering :-)